# $\lim_{t \to 0} \frac1{t} \int_{\mathbb R} |f(x+t) -f(x)|dx=0 \implies f =0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> Suppose $f$ is Lebesgue integrable on $\mathbb R$ and satisfies:
>
> $$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac1{t} \int_{\mathbb R} |f(x+t)-f(x)|dx = 0$$
>
> Prove that $f = 0$ almost everywhere.

It seems to me that there is no way to solve this problem using elementary methods. If $f$ is differentiable we can use Fatou's lemma as follows: let $g_n(x) = n\left( f\left(x + \frac1n \right) - f(x) \right)$.

$$\int_{\mathbb R} |f'(x)| dx = \int_{\mathbb R} \liminf |g_n(x)| dx  \le \liminf \int_{\mathbb R} |g_n(x)|dx = 0$$

so $f' = 0$ a.e. and $f = c$. Since $f$ is integrable, $c = 0$.

We can always use Fatou's lemma to obtain: $\liminf g_n(x) = 0$ but this doesn't look very useful to me. How to solve this problem?

Comment: What do you consider to be elementary methods? It seems to me you have a good, elementary proof there already!

Comment: @Bowditch by elementary I mean using the basic theorems in measure theory (that's horribly vague, I know). I don't see where I proved anything - I had to assume differentiability for my argument to work, but $f$ need not be differentiable.

Comment: Have you seen distributions? For all $\phi\in C_c^\infty$, you'll have $-\int f(x)\phi'(x)dx =0$ so that $f$ is a.e. differentiable with derivative 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe the Fourier transform?  Let $h_t(x)=\frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{t}$, with $\widehat h_t(\xi)=\frac{e^{it\xi}-1}{t}\widehat f(\xi)$.  The condition $\|h_t\|_1\to 0$ implies $\|\widehat h_t\|_\infty\to 0$, which seems to imply $\widehat f(\xi)=0$, since $\widehat h_t(\xi)\to i\xi \widehat f(\xi)$.  By continuity, it would seem $\widehat f(0)=0$ as well.

Comment: Nice idea. But I don't see what $\widehat {f}(0) = 0$ would imply ($f$ is not necessarily nonnegative)

Comment: It just implies $\widehat f(\xi)=0$ on $\mathbb R$ rather than $\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: What does this imply about $f$? (and why?)

Comment: Since $f$ and $\widehat f$ are integrable, the Fourier inversion theorem holds, so this gives $f=0$.

Comment: Oh right! This is very neat. I would definitely accept your answer, but I want to wait to see if someone can come up with a solution not involving Fourier transforms.

Comment: Fair enough. I am also interested to see such a solution.